# How to add a multiline text fields values in a single cell of excel in Sitecore MVC

Tags: sitecore-api

I am using Sitecore 8.0 . We have one Export of data feature using Excel. For all the fields the data is getting exported in a cell properly ,but for the Multiline text field the text is getting shifted to a next line of the cell .

Here is the code to generate excel file data:

```
public static string GetCSVFile(DataTable dt)
    {
        //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
            string csv = string.Empty;
            StringBuilder strbld = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
            //Add the Header row for CSV file.
            strbld.Append(column.ColumnName + ',');
            }

            //Add new line.
            strbld.Append("\r\n");

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    //Add the Data rows.
                    strbld.Append(row[column.ColumnName].ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',');
                }

                //Add new line.
                strbld.Append("\r\n");
            }

            csv = strbld.ToString();
            return csv;
        
    }
```

Below is the screenshot of generated excel file for the multiline text field highlighted in yellow:
[image]

Can anyone please tell how to do place this multiline text field in a single cell .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use the below regular expressions code to remove all the occurrences of `\n`,`\r` (new line) or `\t` (tab) from the string.

```
string replacement = Regex.Replace(s, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

So, in your code, you can use it like below:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    //Add the Data rows.
                    string colData= Regex.Replace(row[column.ColumnName].ToString(), @"\t|\n|\r", "");
                    strbld.Append(colData.Replace(",", ";") + ',');
                }
```